# Updating user after successful transaction/Storing hashed pword as session var

Tags: php, authentication

I have a web application with free and paid plans.

The user chooses a plan and then signs up. After sign up and before he pays I log the user in with a free account. Once he pays and the transaction callback is successful, I want to log him in again with the new plan that he paid for. One way I thought of doing this is:

1) user signs up
2) he is registered with a free account and the hashed password is stored as a php session var
3) he pays
4) transaction is successful
5) i call a php file that looks up the hashed password session var and updates the user based on that

Is there anything apparently wrong with this method? Is it OK to use the hashed pword as a session var? Are there any obvious security risks with this flow?

Comment: Do things internally in your code fundamentally change when you switch someone from free->paid? If your code simply has a bunch of `if (isPaid()) { ... }` type flags, wouldn't it simply be simpler to set a `paid` flag in that user's session, without forcing a re-login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security point of view, I always stay away from using passwords for any identifier what-so-ever.  Plus! - users can have the same password, so it may not be unique (sure, you may be salting your hash, but depending on how unique your salt is, you can still have this problem...)

In your session, I'm assuming you're storing your own unique identifier for the user.  This is how you'd look that up.  You could then change the role of the user (or the plan) in the database.

If you need to have that change immediately, in real time, you have two options:

Your user authentication and authorization system could hit the database each page load to get the newest user information.  This is probably not a great idea because you only really need this feature one time in the user's "lifespan."

The second option would be to set a setting with the user's session after payment that tells it to only check the database THEN on each page load.  Once you have updated the database, and the user sees the change, applies it to the current user, that flag could be turned off, so it doesn't keep querying the database.

There are of course other options: you can delete the user's session either in your temp files or in the db (if you are using db to store the session information) and force them to login.  I'm sure there are many more, but I would suggest the temporary proactive approach above (number 2).

If you need any more clarification, I'd love to help.  Post a comment! :)